# Seating in round table - arrangements with b next to a or c

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

8 people sit around a round table. Arrangements are considered the same if the same student is to the right/left. So, in total there are $7! = 5040$ ways to seat.

Part 1: How many arrangements are there with B sitting next to both A and C?

- For this one, I think that B would have to be in the middle, and there are 2 ways to place B between A and C. So, $2!\cdot5! =$ **240 ways**.

Part 2: How many arrangements are there with B sitting next to A or C?

- For this one, I was thinking about subtracting from the opposite: B will sit next to anyone other than A/C.
- So, $7! - 6 \cdot 1\cdot 4\cdot 5!=$ **2160 ways**.

Can anyone tell my approach looks good / verify my answers?

Comment: Part 1 is correct. For part 2, I see a mistake which may be conceptual or a typo. In the expression $7!-6\cdot 4\cdot 5!$, where does the $6$ come from?

Comment: Well, my reasoning was arranging X b X .... where X is anything other than a or c, so we are selecting from $8-2=6$ in the first spot, $1$ for b, and $6-2=4$ for the third spot, and 5, 4, 3, 2, ... for the remaining spots.

Comment: You subtracted $8-2$ because $X$ cannot be $a$ or $c$, but you forgot that $X$ can also not be $b$.

Comment: Oh right, so would it be $5*1*3*5!$ in that case?

Comment: Almost! Now, the $3$ is not correct.

Comment: So $5*1*4*5!$ because the b was already selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to part $1$ is correct.

When counting the arrangements where $B$ is next to neither $A$ nor $C$, there are...

- $5$ choices for the person sitting on $B$'s left; anyone but $A$, $B$ or $C$. [*You had $6$ for this number, which was your mistake.*]
- $4$ choices for the person sitting on $B$'s right; anyone but $A$, $B$, $C$, or the person sitting on $B$'s right.
- $5!$ ways to choose everyone else; $5$ choices for the person $2$ places to the right of $B$, $4$ choices for the person $3$ places to the right, etc.

Finally, the answer is $\boxed{7!-5\cdot 4\cdot 5!}$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.